# How can you make BufferedReader.readLine() not hang?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Is there a way to make `BufferedReader.readLine()` not hang?

I'm creating a server that:

- Checks if the client has delivered any input.
- If not, it executes other code and eventually loops back to checking the client for input.

How can I check if the client has delivered any input without running `readLine()`?  If I run `readLine()`, the thread will hang until input is delivered?

Comment: Why? The server should have a separate reading thread per client if you're using blocking I/O.

Comment: I don't want to have to create two threads for each user.  I already have one thread for each user.

Comment: This is the unfortunate reality of Java's I/O library. You can either 
1) Spin up separate threads for reading
2) Use the NIO library
3) Don't use readLine() and do your own buffering and end-of-line management yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `BufferedReader.ready()`, like this:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(); //Initialize your BufferedReader in the way you have been doing before, not like this.

if(b.ready()){
    String input = b.readLine();
}
```

`ready()` will return `true` if the source of the input has not put anything into the stream that has not been read.

Edit:  Just a note, ready will return `true` whenever even only one character is present.  You can use `read()` to check if there is a line feed or carriage return, and those would indicate an end of line.

For more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready()

Comment: Doesn't this only guarantee that the next call to `read()` doesn't block? The link says nothing about `readLine()`.

Comment: Even if it is ready, that only means that there is at least one byte, not necessarily a whole line.  This won't necessarily work in all cases, though you may get lucky and it will work for what you are doing.